# Unexpected behaviour when rendering Blazorise charts

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazorise

I am working on investment tracking app that will be free for everyone. I am using net Core with blazor and Blazorise for charts.
I stumbled upon a problem with rendering the charts. From the official Blazorise documentation I added method `protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)` (see in the code below). This method should redraw the charts the first time the page renders. The problem is that this method always fires twice. It renders the charts in the first go and the second time it leaves them empty (as firstRender = false the second time it fires). If I remove the if block the charts render ok.

Furthermore I've added button that should refresh the data + charts. After pressing this button the charts refresh twice (this is unwanted behaviour as it distracts the users) and what is interesting the data itself (the values) change after the second go.

Have anybody dealt with this problem before?

My html code

```
...
<div class="btn" @onclick="(async () => await RerenderPage())">Refresh Data</div>
...
```

My code

```
List<Models.VM.OverView> overview = new List<Models.VM.OverView>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    overview = await GetOverview(); //gets overview from api
}
        
public async Task<List<Models.VM.OverView>> GetOverview()
{
 return await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Models.VM.OverView>>("/api/Overview/GetOverView/" + await GetUserIdAsync);
}
        
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
     if (firstRender)
     {
         await HandleRedraw();
     }        
}
        
async Task HandleRedraw()
{
    await pieChart.Clear();


    //this method goes in the overview object and gets data from it
    await pieChart.AddLabelsDatasetsAndUpdate(GetLabelsPieChart(), GetPieChartDataset());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the await Rerenderpage() doing ?
From the samples it looks like it employs the user of a bool isAlreadyInitialised flag.

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync( bool firstRender )
    {
        if ( !isAlreadyInitialised )
        {
           isAlreadyInitialised = true;
           await HandleRedraw();
        }
    }
```

I am assuming that async () => await RerenderPage()) calls something that then calls the chart.Update in order for the component to know its statuschanged ?